# Override module method from another module

Tags: ruby

I want to override a method from a module A from another module B that will monkey-patch A.
http://codepad.org/LPMCuszt

```
module A
  def foo; puts 'A' end
end

module B
  def foo; puts 'B'; super; end
end

A.module_eval { include B } # why no override ???

class C
  include A
end

# must print 'A B', but only prints 'A' :(
C.new.foo
```

Comment: This was an `alias_method_chain` case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
module A
  def foo
    puts 'A'
  end
end

module B
  def foo
    puts 'B'
    super
  end
end

include A # you need to include module A before you can override method

A.module_eval { include B }

class C
  include A
end

C.new.foo # => B A
```

Comment: Indeed your solution works but this behavior annoying, I don't want to include the module somewhere where it's not needed. Any ideas on why ruby behaves like this ?

Answer (score 3):

Including a module places it *above* the module/class that is including it in the class hierarchy. In other words, A#foo is not super of B#foo but rather the other way round.

If you think of including a module as a way of doing multiple inheritance this makes sense, `include SomeModule` is a way of saying, "Treat SomeModule like it is a parent class for me".

To get the output you wanted you need to reverse the inclusion so that B includes A:

```
module A
  def foo; puts 'A' end
end

module B
  def foo; puts 'B'; super; end
end

B.module_eval { include A } # Reversing the inclusion

class C
  include B # not include A
end

puts C.new.foo
```

---

Edit in response to comment:

Then either include both A and B in C with B included after A:

```
# A and B as before without including B in A.

class C
  include A
  include B
end
```

or patch A in C itself and don't bother with B.

```
# A as before, no B.

class C
  include A

  def foo; puts 'B'; super; end
end
```

The only way for this to work is if the method lookup on C is C -> B -> A and there is no way to do this without including B into C.

Comment: it is a requirement for C to include A and not B, and what I need is to monkey patch A.

Comment: I cannot modify C. I can only monkey patch A.

Comment: @clyfe Why can't you modify C?

Comment: A is in a gem, B is another gem that extends the functionality in A, and I don't want future users to have to do additional steps other than install and include gem B in project.

Answer (score 1):

This is also one solution to your question. I am trying to achieve with **module hooks** `included`. When you include the *module A* into *class C*. **included** callbacks defined in *module A* is called and executed. We included the *module B* on-fly. So our *module A* method **foo** is overridden by *Module B* **foo** to print the superclass module method just called *super*.

```
module A
  def self.included klass
    klass.send(:include, B)
  end
  def foo
    puts 'A'
  end
 end

module B
  def foo
   super
   puts 'B'
  end
end

class C
 include A
end
C.new.foo #out put A,B
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to accomplish this is to include module B when module A is included.

```
module A
  def foo
    puts "this should never be called!"
    "a"
  end
end

module B
  def foo
    "b"
  end
end

module A
  def self.included(base)
    base.class_eval do
      include B
    end
  end
end

class C
  include A
end

C.new.foo # "b"
```