# Overwriting a dependency gem class which inherits from a parent class

Tags: ruby, class, rubygems

**Overwriting a dependency gem class which inherits from a parent class**

If I am using `blah` gem, and this gem has a class called `foo` which inherits from `bar`. But I want to change this class on this gem. Is there a way I can do that, I have seen ways to overwrite methods on classes from gems but not to overwrite the actual classes.

eg.

The class I want to overwrite is as follows:

```
class foo < bar
  def some_method
  end

  def another_method
  end
end
```

How I want to overwrite this class:

```
class foo < not_bar
  def a_different_some_method
  end

  def a_different_another_method
  end
end
```

Comment: Class names start with a capital letter. And you probably want to have the same method names but with different implementations.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Override module method from another module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4900167/override-module-method-from-another-module)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't actually *change* the parent class without basically rewriting the subclass. If you only have two methods in each class that's probably fine, but Ruby classes use single-inheritance, so you can't re-assign a subclass to a different superclass without redefining it. You can, however, do any of the following:

1. Re-open the class and redefine its methods.
2. Prepend a module to redefine the behavior of existing methods.
3. Add or modify methods for the singleton class, or on a singleton instance of that class.
4. If your class is inheriting from Delegator, you can change the delegate class with [#__setobj__](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.0.2/libdoc/delegate/rdoc/Delegator.html).

Since you haven't really defined a use case, it's hard to tell which method would be best for you. Once the parent class is defined, though, it stays defined, so you'll have to do whatever you're trying to do another way.

Comment: Hey, yes sorry for lack of context. I will expand here.

I basically have dependency where it doesn't work with the latest version of ruby. But I cant update the version as the version is locked by another gem.
The reason it won't work is that there is a class which inherits from SortedSet, this has been deprecated in the version of Ruby I want to use. 

I have the code which would update that class to use Set instead of Sorted Set, so I am wondering how I could override this class and use my own. If there is a way, and from the answer above it seems not.